# HTML5 DIV not draggable in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have the following code at https://jsfiddle.net/42jg2kxq/15/ to drop a green div into a bigger div. The div is now draggble, but can't be drop into the bigger box in Chrome. It looks like the event function on "drop" event never get run.

JS

```
var dragImages = {
     'drop':function(){
          $('.dropbox').on('drop', function(ev) {
             ev.preventDefault();
             var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
             ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
         });

         $('.dropbox').on('dragover', function(ev) {
             ev.preventDefault();
         });   
     },

     'drag':function(){
          $('.drag').on('dragstart', function(ev) {
              ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
          });
     }
};

dragImages.drag();
dragImages.drop();
```

HTML

```
<div id="box1" class="drag"  draggable="true">box 1</div>

<br/>

<div id="box2"  class="drag"  draggable="true"> box 2</div>
<br/>

<img src="" class="drag"  draggable="true"> image </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it a little differently using the method on w3fools http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop, 
see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/42jg2kxq/16/

```
<div class="dropbox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="box1" class="drag"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">box 1</div>

<br/>

<div id="box2"  class="drag"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> box 2</div>
<br/>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="drag"  draggable="true">
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo and code. Setting `draggable="true"` on Firefox doesn't seem to be enough to allow an item to be dragged. I needed to call the function`event.dataTransfer.setData` in order for the `drag` event to be fired.

Comment: @Dave F - isn't that putting the cart before the horse?  How can you call reference event before the event happens???

Comment: @nuander See the [Data​Transfer​.set​Data() MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData).

Answer (score 0):

You should be listening to the 'dragend' event for the element you're dragging, and 'drop' on the place you're dropping.

```
function handleDragEnd() {
  // 'dragend' logic goes here
}

some_el.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
```

[Demo, by me](http://antibland.github.io/playground/native_drag/)

[Code for demo](https://github.com/antibland/playground/blob/gh-pages/native_drag/js/native_drag.js)

Comment: for what it's worth, this demo does not work for me in chrome (nothing is draggable), using Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m -- no errors in console.

Comment: @ShaunWilson Now sure what happened. Tested in Chrome 52.0.2743.82 on several different machines and things are working fine.